# How to use nfcpy for MiFare 1k classic

Tags: python, nfc

I bought the card reader ACR122U and try to read mifare 1k classic cards with nfcpy.
So my question is, how can i read or write on a mifare 1k classic card using nfcpy?

Answer (score 2):

Nfcpy only supports the standardized NFC Forum Type 1, 2, 3, and 4 Tags. Mifare 1K Classic uses a proprietary communication format and requires reader hardware with NXP Crypto-1 support.